# NSInvalidArgumentException - XCode 6.0.1

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, invalidargumentexception

I realize this error has been discussed many times on stackoverflow, but I'm still not sure what I'm missing. Here's the console output:

```
Unknown class CRBarGraphController in Interface Builder file.
2014-11-18 18:40:05.796 Test[7319:60b] -[UIImageView start2]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x16562ac0
2014-11-18 18:40:06.256 Test[7319:60b] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[UIImageView start2]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x16562ac0'
```

`CRBarGraphController.m` defines a function `(void)start2;` also declared in the interface for `CRBarGraphController.h`.

start2 is called from `CRGraphViewController.m` using the following code:

```
-(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    self.navigationController.navigationBarHidden = NO;
    [self.bar_Graph start2];
}
```

where, bar_Graph is an object of `CRBarGraphController`, declared in `CRGraphViewController.h` as:

```
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet CRBarGraphController *bar_Graph;
```

`CRGraphViewController.h` does import `CRBarGraphController.h` 
Also, in the storyboard, bar_Graph outlet is set to class, `CRBarGraphController`.

Why does XCode still think bar_Graph is an instance of `UIImageView` and not `CRBarGraphComtroller`? I included an exception breakpoint to make sure the exception originates from where start2 is being called.

Comment: Did you declare the start2 method in both the .h and .m files?

Comment: Yes, I declared it in the interfaces of both CRBarGraphController.h and CRBarGraphController.m.

Comment: By looking into the XML project definition file, is the object defined as a CRBarGraphController? If so, could you try cleaning the project and rebuilding it again? Sometimes XCode gets messed up.

Comment: I did a clean (command+shift+k) & rebuild as well as a clean build folder (command+option+shift+k) & rebuild, and got the same result. I'm not sure where to find the XML project definition file. Could you please explain?